# How to handle condition inside mergeMap?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe, mergemap

```
Obs1$.pipe(
  mergeMap((data) => {
    if (data.condition) {
      const generatedStuff = doSomethingFunction(data1);
      return generatedStuff.Obs2$;
    }

    someCleanupAction();

    return of(null); // I want to get rid this because I don't want doSomethingElse() to be called when a condition is false happens
  })
).subscribe(() => {
  doSomethingElse();
})
```

The above is my current code based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74552146/5195033.

Like my comment above, I just I want `doSomethingElse()` to be called when the condition is `true`.

Expectedly, commenting out `return of(null);` gives:

```
Type 'Subject<void> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) instead of `of(null)`.

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

Obs1$.pipe(
  mergeMap((data) => {
    if (data.condition) {
      const generatedStuff = doSomethingFunction(data1);
      return generatedStuff.Obs2$;
    }

    someCleanupAction();

    return EMPTY
  })
).subscribe(() => {
  doSomethingElse();
})
```

Comment: Awesome. Didn't even know such a thing existed and it was exactly what I needed.